# strange rspec expect behavior with rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm new to rails and rspec, and can't understand why this test fails:

```
describe 'adding a friend' do
  it 'updates friends' do
    user = create(:user)
    expect {
      user.friends << create(:user)
    }.to change{user.friends}
  end
end
```

The test fails with:

```
Failure/Error: expect {
result should have changed, but is still #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 1445, ...>]>
```

I used byebug to confirm that the friends collection is initially empty, and the rspec failure message shows that the expect block does modify the collection.

Furthermore, this test does pass:

```
it 'sanity test' do
  a = []
  expect {
    a << 1
  }.to change{a}
end
```

so I'm not sure what the problem is. Is it the way that rails models implement equality? Or is it the fact that I'm using Factory-girl?
And how would I go about testing that the friends collection was modified?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Haven't used rspec in a while but have you tried `user.reload.friends`?

Comment: I just tried adding 'user.reload.friends' to the end of the expect block, but that doesn't help. Is that what you meant?
Also this is a simplification of my actual test - in the original, I'm testing a method that adds to the friends collection and then saves the model (which, unless I am mistaken, would remove the need to reload?)

Comment: Yeah thats what I meant. Perhaps `change{UserFriend.count}.by(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the spec, check that friends `count` has changed:

```
user = create(:user)
expect {
  user.friends << create(:user)
}.to change{user.friends.count}.by(1)
```

However, this is a really poor test. First, it's not testing any of your own code.  It tests default Rails behavior that is already covered by Rails own test suite.  Second, it would be better to test that the correct friend shows up in the new friends collection instead of just asserting that the friends collection has changed:

```
user = create(:user)
friend = create(:user)
user.friends << friend

expect(user.friends).to include(friend)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer in the question: the spec is a simplification of my actual code (I'm testing a method that modifies friends among other things) and I've rewritten to use include instead of change as you suggested). However, as I'm learning rails and rspec, I would like to know why this doesn't work..